# How to use a variable "holding" a string value as list name?

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, variables

One of the parameter the I want to pass to a Class **init** is a variable with a string value. this string value is a name of a list. The **init** should use this string value to append the class object to that list. what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried using the locals() and globals() but it ended with "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'". tried also vars() with no use as well.

```
refList = []
cmpList = []

class Part(object):
    def __init__(self, origin, name, type, listName):
        self.origin = origin
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        partListName = locals()[listName]
        partListName.append(self)

#... some file parsing..

part1 = Part((str(origin), str(name) ,str(type), 'refList') 

# ... some other file parsing ...

part2 = Part((str(origin), str(name) ,str(type), 'cmpList')
```

Comment: Fisrt of all, you should rename your class name to `class Part` according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Comment: Second, why would you do that ? What is your approach or your final goal doing this?

Comment: thank you for your replay and clarification. I'm expecting large number of objects generated from two different files. I would like to find the specific objects that differs between the two files. using lists enables fast seek and find. (o(n) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Welcome to SO Ram!** I think you should rethink your code because this is not a good approach to do it always. It is better for example pass directly the list or something related.

However your issue with your code is that you should use the `globals()` function. I really recommend you see the next post in order to get more knowledge about how/when use this useful functionality of Python3.

Also, you must declarate your variables with `global` keywoard because you are going to reference this variables from your `Part` class.

```
global refList = []
global cmpList = []
```

Said all this, your critical code line should look like:

```
partListName = globals()[listName]
```